# Choose <li> bullet if parent is <ol> or <ul>

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xsl-fo

I want to check if the parent of the current `<li>` is either `<ol>` or `<ul>` and then insert the appropriate bullet.

Here is a piece of what I am working with. The current output has the black round dots and I know that  is present but mot being picked up on.

```
<xsl:when test="$tag = 'LI' and $closeTagIndex &gt; 0">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$htmloutput = 'false'">
      <fo:list-item relative-align="baseline">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="parent::ol = 'ol'">
            <fo:list-item-label>
              <fo:block><xsl:number/>.</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:list-item-label>
              <fo:block>●</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know but would it be easier to first find all the `<ol>` and `<ul>` and then find their direct children `<li>`s?

Comment: I would use templates matching ol/li and ul/li

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace this..

```
<xsl:when test="parent::ol = 'ol'">
```

With this....

```
<xsl:when test="parent::ol">
```

Your current check is checking that the parent is `ol` and that it has text value of "ol".